# Does android support 4K resolution screenshot?

Tags: android, screenshot

I heard some SONY Z5 Permium users said android is not supported 4K screenshot yet,

when you take a screenshot on a 4K device will downscale to 1080p,

but I have a LG G4, I can take 2K screenshot without this problem

is it Sony's problem or android's?

Comment: You might wanna go to `android enthusiasts` channel...? http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

"I heard some SONY Z5 Permium users said android is not supported 4K screenshot yet."

This statement is in fact incorrect. Sony will use 4K for images and video, but for everything else, it will use regular 1080p. Therefore, all screenshots(being images) will be at 4K.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it last week,

you can take a screenshot when your screen resolution is **under 3K**,

otherwise you will get a message which tells you the action is not supported.

---

To test it, change your screen resolution with the following command (no root needed):

```
adb shell wm size 2160x4096
```